# How To Bind A Combobox to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

In the code below I've used the LINQ method to work with my 
dataset and was successful in displaying the list of names in the combobox and displaying the data table in the GridView. The problem I'm having is getting the combo box and the gridview connected to each other, so that when a customer is selected in the combo box their records are displayed in the Gridview below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Incident_Maintenance_Form
{
    public partial class frmIncidentMaintenance : Form
    {
        public frmIncidentMaintenance()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TechSupportEntities techSupport = new TechSupportEntities();
```

Below is the LINQ query used that joins the Customers and Incidents table and links the dataset to the combobox

```
                var customers = (from customer in techSupport.Customers
                                 join incidents in techSupport.Incidents
                                 on customer.CustomerID equals 
                                 incidents.CustomerID
                                 orderby customer.Name
                                 where incidents.TechID != null
                                 where incidents.DateOpened != null
                                select new { customer.CustomerID, 
                                customer.Name }).Distinct();
            cmbCustomers.DataSource = customers.ToList();
            cmbCustomers.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cmbCustomers.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
```

Below is the LINQ query used that joins the Customers and Incidents table and links the datasource to the datagridview

```
                var products = from customer in techSupport.Customers
                               from incident in customer.Incidents

                               select new
                               {
                                   incident.ProductCode,
                                   incident.TechID,
                                   incident.Title,
                                   incident.DateOpened,
                                   incident.DateClosed,
                                   incident.Description
                               };


                dataGridView1.DataSource = products.ToList();
            //    customersBindingSource.DataSource = customers.ToList();


            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'techSupportDataSet.Customers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            //  this.customersTableAdapter.Fill(this.techSupportDataSet.Customers);

        }
```

Below is the code I am trying to used to link the combobox to the datagridview.

```
        private void cmbCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TechSupportEntities techSupport = new TechSupportEntities();


            var customers = (from customer in techSupport.Customers
                             join incidents in techSupport.Incidents
                             on customer.CustomerID equals incidents.CustomerID
                             orderby customer.Name
                             where incidents.TechID != null
                             where incidents.DateOpened != null
                             select new {
                                 incidents.ProductCode,
                                 incidents.TechID,
                                 incidents.Title,
                                 incidents.DateOpened,
                                 incidents.DateClosed,
                                 incidents.Description}).Distinct();


            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = techSupport;

        }

        private void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to bind `customers`, not `techSupport`?

Comment: Correct!. I'm trying to bind the customers in the combobox to the records being displayed in the datagridview.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not really following but at a glance I don't see you filtering the data in the selected index changed event. Typically you would get the id of the selected item and use that in the WHERE clause of what you bind your grid to.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try to code it and see if I can get it to work. That at least help me to understand what I'm missing.